# Detect number of missing values per dataframe column with dplyr & purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Taking a simple dataframe from the R built-in dataset airquality and checking their missing values:

```
airquality %>% summary
```

While this works:

```
airquality %>% map_df(is.na) %>% map_df(sum)

  Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
  <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    37       7     0     0     0     0
```

, and this - in purrr syntax - works too:

```
airquality %>% map_df(~sum(is.na(.)))
  Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
  <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    37       7     0     0     0     0
```

, this doesn't work:

```
airquality %>% map_df(sum(is.na(.)))

  Ozone Solar.R  Wind  Temp Month   Day
  <int>   <int> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
1    23     148     8    82     6    13
```

My question is: 
How can you explain the last result?

Where exactly does the calculation happen - in dplyr or purrr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the various syntaxes around `%>%` is explained in detail in `help("%>%", package = "magrittr")`.

In this specific instance, `sum(is.na(.))` isn't interpreted as an anonymous function, like OP seems to expect, thus `.` isn't the argument to an anonymous function.

Instead, `.` is the LHS (left hand side) of the pipe.

`airquality %>% map_df(sum(is.na(.)))` could be unfolded as `map_df(airquality, .f = sum(is.na(airquality)))`.

`sum(is.na(airquality))` evals to `44`, and from `help("map_df")`, if the `.f` argument to `map_df` is a numeric vector,

> it is converted to an extractor function

*Summing up:* this is extracting the 44th element of each column, and constraining it back to a data frame. Or, with some oversimplification, this extracts the 44th row.

Comment: The answer by @Aurèle really enlightened my understanding. So I came up with a simple heuristic how to "read" the purrr syntax of an anonymous function: map + ~ means: "apply per column". So in my problem, as the tilde (~) is missing, it will *not* be applied per column, so the argument must be evaluated independently. Big credits to  Aurèle.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help. If this answers your original question, consider accepting it as an answer :)

Comment: Hi @Aurèle I thought I did by upvoting it - or is there another way?

Comment: Ah I just figured it out, the icon below the downvote!